# XMLHttpRequest falhando devido a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' [React/Mongo/Axios]

Tags: mongodb, react, cors, xmlhttprequest, axios

Tenho um backend rodando em localhost com o seguinte codigo:

server.js:

```
const port = 3003
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const server = express()
const allowCors = require('./cors')

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
server.use(bodyParser.json())
server.use(allowCors)

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`BACKEND rodando na porta ${port}.`)
})

module.exports = server
```

cors.js:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Acess-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header('Acess-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
    res.header('Acess-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    next()
}
```

Quando faco um request via Postman, tudo ocorre bem e funciona, consigo usar POST e GET, porém no frontend, quando eu faco um request via axios, sou retornado esse erro:

Erro:

[image: Erro]

Request:

```
Axios.post('http://localhost:3003/api/todos', {description}).then(resp => console.log('Funcionou!'))
```

Mais codigo do backend:

routes.js:

```
const express = require('express')

module.exports = function(server) {

    //API Routes
    const router = express.Router()
    server.use('/api', router)

    //TODO Routes
    const todoService = require('../api/todo/todoService')
    todoService.register(router, '/todos')
}
```

todoService.js:

```
const Todo = require('./todo')

Todo.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'])
Todo.updateOptions({new: true, runValidators: true})

module.exports = Todo
```

Tudo me faz crer que errei de alguma forma a configuracao do CORS, mas ja tentei de tudo e nao consigo acertar

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar uma biblioteca ao seu Express chamada [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). Ela abstrai essa parte do request e habilita o cross origin.

Para usar é bem simples:

```
const port = 3003
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express')
const server = express()

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
server.use(bodyParser.json())
server.use(cors())


server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`BACKEND rodando na porta ${port}.`)
})

module.exports = server
```